# Avdmanager command not found

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, avd-manager

I'm trying to create a custom AVD from cmdl on CodeMagic CI **Linux** machine because I have no access to the avdmanager GUI, but I'm getting this error
`avdmanager: command not found`

The command:

```
$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin avdmanager create avd -n pixel2 -k pixel2 "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86_64" --device "Pixel 2"
```

And i tried to run it in both tools path and cmdline-tools path of Android SDK

Comment: `SDK_path/tools/bin/avdmanager` works. I see you have a space there after `bin`, check again without space and a forward slash.